# margin: 0 auto; after hiding another li elements with search

Tags: javascript

How to disable `float: left` and set `margin: 0 auto` after hiding all elements that are not specified in search bar?

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";

        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rmjfhq8q/

Comment: You may find it easier to use `flexbox` and centre align all `li` elements be default. Then you wouldn't need to change any styles after a search has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for

```
parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/vL45jztc/). Don't forget to [prefix](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: @Deadweight... and I also fixed the double border problem ^^

Comment: Unless he wanted the double border xD